# Unable to open Update Manager after Upgrading 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

While upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04, the computer hung up and I had to force shutdown. Later when I realized the Ubuntu is not working, I went to recovery mode and said repair packages. Then it opened normally but now I can't find Update manager or network connections in my desktop. I don't know where to find them also.

I've enough disk space and I'm using HP Pavilion DM4.

Comment: have you tired with gksu update-manager , is it opened anything ? do you have synaptic  ?

Answer (score 1):

If your /home is on a separate partition, your best option is to use a live cd/usb and do the install without formatting the /home partition. If it is not, then copy your files on a separate drive, and do a full/clean install.

It is easier than making a repaired install work perfectly.